# how to display comments with ajax submit call on the same post detail page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to display user comments after they click on the comment submit button. I added an ajax call on my comment section. However when i click on the submit button after writing a comment, Page is not refreshing but it is not displaying the new comment right away. Only after i refresh the page my new comment is available. I want to display new comment on the page right after clicking the submit button without reloading the page.
I am unable to figure out what is going wrong here, my codes are as follow:

at the end of base.html

```
<script>
        $(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log($(this).serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    $('.main-comment-section').html(response['form']);
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                    console.log(rs.responseText);
                },
            });
        });
```

in post_detail.html, i am calling comment_section.html using the following

```
        <div class="main-comment-section">
            {% include 'webpage/comment_section.html' %}
        </div>
```

My comment_section.html

```
    <h1>New comment</h1>

<form method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="save btn btn-outline-success">
</form>
    {{ comments.count }} Comments</h3>
            <!-- comments -->

        {% for comment in comments %}
            <article class="media comment">
                <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ comment.author.profile.image.url }}">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="article-metadata">
                        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-profile' comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }} {{ comment.author.last_name }}</a>
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_date }}</small>
                    </div>

                    <p class="article-content" "mr-4">{{ comment.content | linebreaks }}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div class="reply">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="{{ comment_id }}" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                                {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Comment</button>
                            </form>        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% empty %}
            <pclass="article-content" "mr-4"> No comments here yet :(</p>

        {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    slug_field = 'slug' # DetailView's default value: optional
    form_class = CommentForm
    def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        comments= Comment.objects.filter(post=post)

        context = super(PostDetailView,self).get_context_data()
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'post': self.object, 'author': self.request.user})
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["post"] = post
        return context

        if self.request.is_ajax():
            html = render_to_string('webpage/comment_section.html', context, request=self.request)
            return JsonResponse({'form': html})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(PostDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['author','content', 'post']
    widgets = {
    'content' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Write a comment here', 'rows':'4', 'cols': '50'}),
    'author' : forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'value':'', 'id':'Idspacename', 'type':'hidden'}),
    'post' : forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'value':'', 'id':'Idspacename', 'type':'hidden'}),

    }
```

and urls.py

```
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because you're posting the comment but it doesn't exist in your store. That's why reloading works because it fetch again all the datas. Your code only push it to API.

Comment: Can you please help me with this? How can i load the comment?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer on the javascript part, first you need to create wrapper for the comment list. If you get the response from success you can append the element into the wrapper.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: your_url,
  data: your_data,
  success(function(response) {
    const comment_list = document.getElementById('comment_list');

    const _el = document.createElement('article');
    _el.setAttribute('class', 'media comment');

    const _elImg = document.createElement('img');
    _elImg.setAttribute('class', 'rounded-circle article-img')
    _elImg.setAttribute('src', response.author.profile.image.url);
    const mediaBody = document.createElement('div');
    mediaBody.setAttribute('class', 'media-body');
    const metaData = document.createElement('div');
    metaData.setAttribute('class', 'article-metadata');
    metaData.innerHTML = '<a class="mr-2" href="url_to_profile' + response.author.username '">' + response.author.first_name + response.author.last_name '</a><small class="text-muted">' + response.created_date + '</small>';

    const commentContent = document.createElement("p");
    commentContent.setAttribute("article-content mr-4");
    commentContent.innerHTML = response.content;

    mediaBody.appendChild(metaData);
    mediaBody.appendChild(commentContent);
    _el.appendChild(_elImg);
    _el.appendChild(mediaBody);
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="comment_list">
  <!-- foreach starting here and loop this below element -->
  <article class="media comment">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ comment.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="article-metadata">
        <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-profile' comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }} {{ comment.author.last_name }}</a>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_date }}</small>
      </div>

      <p class="article-content" "mr-4">{{ comment.content | linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <!-- end foreach -->
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried your javascript code but this reloads the whole page and add the comment. I want to add comment without reloading the page. Can you please help me in that?